# Show ellipsis for formatted text generated from text editor displayed in div tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, editor

Some text is entered using an editor. The editor converts the text to a corresponding html. I have to show this text as a small note like display with ellipsis in case the text is too long.

Please find the plunker here: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/JsN25SForCDnUScc79UG?p=preview)

Note that the the text is not a plain text it is an html. I tried overflow hidden but I have to show ellipsis if the text is too long.

My CSS:

```
.note{
  padding:10px;
  background:#e2e2e2;
  height:150px;
  width:200px;
}
```

[edit]
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhMSR.png)

Comment: Did this help you solve the issue?

Answer (score 4):

What you need is:

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

But if you add those to the note class it will look weird, since the element with the note class has block child elements.

**Demo:** https://plnkr.co/edit/AJYQU37AwZssvMTAZZvQ?p=preview

Not sure exactly what you need, but here is one alternative:

```
.note {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #e2e2e2;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.note u {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**Demo:** https://plnkr.co/edit/TFCGTJhifw2wF6oWv83x?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The tags inside note container are just example it can be anything generated from CK Editor. I don't have control over it. I have set character limit using js for the note text. But the problem is when somebody adds some text and hit enter and repeat the process the character limit won't work.

Comment: Do you mean this won't work for you? Can you replicate the real scenario in a plunker? Hard to help otherwise.

Comment: Yes. It won't work. I have updated the question and added one image to depict the problem. Thank you
[edit] So the text typed in editor which will have any type of formatting including line height will be shown in note box  where I have set text limit of 100 char using js. But the problem is when somebody add text by hitting enter many times the text limit becomes unusable as the enter takes each text to new line and overflows the box as the text  limit won't be reached.

Comment: Unless you replicate the real scenario in a plunker, I can't help. Not going to just guess, sorry.